# How to find unbounded vectors corresponding to a sequence of matrices

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, sequences-and-series, matrices, limits

Given a sequence of $n \times n$ matrices $(M_k)_{k=0}^\infty$ with complex entries, where the matrix norm of the sequence is unbounded, that is $\lim_{k \to \infty} \|M_k\| = \infty$, how can I find all the vectors $v$ for which $\lim_{k \to \infty} \|M_k v\| = \infty$?